# How can correlation be insignificant but a regression model on the same data have significance?

Tags: regression, correlation, statistical-significance, interpretation

I'm trying to understand some interesting results I found during an analysis.  For context, I'm trying to see if an onboarding assessment is predictive of future performance.  Performance on the test is measured as a percentage of correct answers, and future performance is measured with a continuous measurement here.  I calculated the both pearson's and spearman's correlation between the performance on the test and future performance and both showed no significant correlation.

Next, I converted each of the questions from the onboarding assessment into binary variables (yes they got it right/no they didn't) and ran a regression model using each of the binary questions as a feature.  The result showed than a handful of the questions were significant predictors, and the overall f-statistic for the regression was significant.

Here's the strange part -- I went back and recalculated the onboarding assessment scores using only the questions that were significant in the regression.  I expected that these new test scores would be correlated with future performance, since they were based solely on questions that were significant in the regression.  However, that's not the case.  There's still no correlation between the refined onboarding scores and future performance.

Any thoughts on how this could happen?  How can the individual question outcomes be significant in the regression model, but when aggregated into a final test score, not be correlated with the dependent variable of the regression model?

Here's the results of the regression. x1 through x30 are the binary question results (1 if correct, zero if incorrect).  You can see that only a handful of questions had significance.

```
                        OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   R-squared:                       0.102
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.060
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     2.414
Date:                Thu, 05 Apr 2018   Prob (F-statistic):           6.15e-05
Time:                        17:04:09   Log-Likelihood:                -3219.3
No. Observations:                 645   AIC:                             6499.
Df Residuals:                     615   BIC:                             6633.
Df Model:                          29                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const         41.3266     47.805      0.864      0.388     -52.553     135.207
x1             8.5136     11.764      0.724      0.470     -14.588      31.616
x2             6.3152      2.977      2.121      0.034       0.468      12.162
x3            56.3477     16.774      3.359      0.001      23.407      89.288
x4             0.1537      3.942      0.039      0.969      -7.589       7.896
x5             1.2174      3.227      0.377      0.706      -5.120       7.554
x6             3.9401      3.399      1.159      0.247      -2.735      10.615
x7            41.3266     47.805      0.864      0.388     -52.553     135.207
x8           -10.9251      3.556     -3.073      0.002     -17.908      -3.942
x9           -24.0424     36.730     -0.655      0.513     -96.174      48.089
x10           24.4058     16.403      1.488      0.137      -7.806      56.618
x11           -7.7593      9.594     -0.809      0.419     -26.600      11.081
x12           -4.3157      3.221     -1.340      0.181     -10.642       2.010
x13            2.8376      3.140      0.904      0.367      -3.329       9.004
x14            4.7398     10.153      0.467      0.641     -15.200      24.679
x15           -1.5544      8.832     -0.176      0.860     -18.900      15.791
x16           23.3869     15.231      1.536      0.125      -6.524      53.297
x17           -3.7291     21.230     -0.176      0.861     -45.420      37.962
x18            0.6788     14.872      0.046      0.964     -28.528      29.885
x19            2.3619      4.503      0.524      0.600      -6.482      11.206
x20          -43.3174     36.862     -1.175      0.240    -115.707      29.073
x21           10.4665     11.478      0.912      0.362     -12.073      33.006
x22           17.2240     18.939      0.909      0.363     -19.970      54.418
x23          -50.5123     32.342     -1.562      0.119    -114.026      13.002
x24          -11.4135     16.279     -0.701      0.483     -43.382      20.555
x25           -7.0957      4.574     -1.551      0.121     -16.077       1.886
x26          -53.1625     36.804     -1.444      0.149    -125.438      19.113
x27           13.1667      4.927      2.673      0.008       3.492      22.842
x28            6.7227     27.437      0.245      0.807     -47.159      60.604
x29            1.9759      5.304      0.372      0.710      -8.441      12.393
x30          -45.2959     36.722     -1.233      0.218    -117.411      26.819
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                       39.263   Durbin-Watson:                   2.031
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.000   Jarque-Bera (JB):               51.139
Skew:                          -0.528   Prob(JB):                     7.86e-12
Kurtosis:                       3.887   Cond. No.                     2.46e+15
==============================================================================
```

Based on some comments below, I'm also included the percent of test takers who got each question correct.  Many of the questions had close to 100% of the test takers answer correctly, so I wouldn't expect them to be indicative of future performance.

```
question  avg_score   
--------  ---------        
2          0.547486
6          0.625698
13         0.640223
12         0.674860
5          0.683799
8          0.690503
25         0.726257
29         0.815642
4          0.822346
19         0.865922
27         0.883799
15         0.960894
11         0.967598
14         0.972067
21         0.978771
1          0.982123
16         0.984358
18         0.988827
10         0.988827
24         0.989944
17         0.992179
22         0.992179
3          0.993296
20         0.997765
9          0.997765
23         0.997765
28         0.997765
26         0.998883
30         0.998883
7          1.000000
```

Comment: Did all the regression coefficients have the same sign? Also, tell us about sample size and number of questions.

Comment: It's 30 question, and about 900 samples.  All of the insignificant coefficients spanned zero within their confidence intervals, and all of the significant coefficients had positive sign.

Comment: 900 samples and no significant correlation, that would be very low correlation to avoid significance. what size are your correlation coefficients?

Comment: About how large are the probabilities of correct answer?

Comment: I edited the original question to include the output of the regression, since that seems like it would be helpful.  Looks like I was wrong when I was remembering the sample size, it was more like 600 samples.  Regarding the probabilities of a correct answer -- all questions were binary, and many had close to a 100% correct answer rate.  I'll edit the original question to include the correct answer rate for each question as well.  Thanks again for the help on this!